# Time complexity of leetcode 394

Tags: c++, stack, time-complexity

I was trying this problem on leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/

I came across this particular [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/discuss/87651/C%2B%2B-simple-and-clear-solution). Code is below.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string decodeString(string s) {
        stack<string> chars;
        stack<int> nums;
        string res;
        int num = 0;
        for(char c : s) {
            if(isdigit(c)) {
                num = num*10 + (c-'0');                              
            }
            else if(isalpha(c)) {
                res.push_back(c);                
            }
            else if(c == '[') {
                chars.push(res);
                nums.push(num);
                res = "";
                num = 0;
            }
            else if(c == ']') {
                string tmp = res;
                for(int i = 0; i < nums.top()-1; ++i) {
                    res += tmp;
                }
                res = chars.top() + res;
                chars.pop(); nums.pop();
            }
        }
        return res;
     }
};
```

Isn't the time complexity of this solution dependent on the numbers that are present in the string? As we are adding a string that many times. Also I feel if there will be some kind of multiplication going on. For example

For input : `3[ab4[c]]`

In a very crude way won't the complexity be something like 3*(len(ab) + 4*(len(c)). Am I correct?

Comment: Time complexity is more about operations than actual time. Besides, measuring the size of the output isn't all that useful if any correct algorithm has to produce that output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess, not so sure though, you're somewhat right. That would probably be considered `O(N)` though since those coefficients would not have much influence.

Just another version:

```
#include <string>

class Solution {
public:
    std::string decodeString(const std::string &base_string, int &index) {
        std::string decoded;

        while (index < base_string.length() && base_string[index] != ']') {
            if (!std::isdigit(base_string[index])) {
                decoded += base_string[index++];

            } else {
                int full_num = 0;

                while (index < base_string.length() && std::isdigit(base_string[index])) {
                    full_num = full_num * 10 + base_string[index++] - 48;
                }

                index++;
                std::string character = decodeString(base_string, index);
                index++;

                while (full_num-- > 0) {
                    decoded += character;
                }
            }
        }

        return decoded;
    }

    std::string decodeString(std::string s) {
        int index = 0;
        return decodeString(s, index);
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-), and asymptotic time/space complexity analysis in there.

[image]

[Image Courtesy](https://blog.bitsrc.io/algorithms-efficiency-big-o-in-simple-english-adbaedbcdfcf)

Comment: If they are large coefficients, won't they have a decent influence on the complexity?

Comment: Why do you spam that block of boilerplate text after all your answers? It's not related to the question and is essentially a tagline, [which is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @Emma Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say the time complexity of solution is `O(N)`, here `N` is the length of final string, and definitely not the encoded string.

> For input : `3[ab4[c]]`
>
> In a very crude way won't the complexity be something like `3*(len(ab)+ 4*(len(c))`. Am I correct?

You analysis is correct. Time Complexity is also a function of the numbers that are represented inside the string and not only dependent on the length of string. So when you are saying the solution is `O(N)`, N is not the length of encoded string, but the length of string upon decoding it.

For eg. Consider the encoded string to be `n[an[b]]`. Here the output will surely depend on `n`. If say, `n = 3`, the output will be `abbbabbbabbb`. Now, here the length of output is 12. It will not remain static if `n` changes. So, a rough upper bound function will consist of the numbers inside encoded string as well.

---

So, let's try to deduce a time complexity, let's consider a string -

```
n1[a[n2[bn3[c...]]]]
```

In this case, the time complexity is `n1*n2*n3...nk` which is pretty big and would time-out for large n1,n2...,etc.

For another string say -

```
n1[a]n2[b]n2[c]
```

In this case however, the time complexity would be `n1+n2+n3`, which is linear.

So, the final time-complexity is not truly linear in terms of input size, but will vary depending on input numbers as well. We can consider the upper bound to be

```
((N11+N12+...+N1k1)*(N21+N22+...+N2k2)*...*(Nn1+Nn2+...+Nnkn)) ,
 
where, Nij = jth number at ith nested level
       k1,k2...kn = number of numbers at 1st,2nd...nth nested level.
       n = number of total nested level
```

There maybe some tighter bound present. But that's the upper bound I can currently think of right now.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Big O is **never** based on the output, it's related solely to the input.

Comment: @ChrisMM I never said it is dependent on output. I am saying that it is not dependent on length of encoded string. It will depend on length as well as numbers in the encoded string

Comment: You specify `O(N)` with `N` being the length of the final string, which is the output ...

Comment: @ChrisMM So is my analysis wrong? N is length of output string. But that will depend on all numbers inside input string. That's what I am saying in my answer. The time complexity depends on numbers inside encoded string

Comment: All I'm saying, is that `O(N)` is true, but it's based on the size of the input. As mentioned in the comments, and the other answer, the other coefficients wouldn't affect the `O`. The definition of Big O specified _when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity_, which would be the size of the input in this case. If you want to reword your answer to not use Big O notation, then it would be much better. (my issue is with your use of Big O, not your analysis)

Comment: Does that mean that input strings - `1000[a1000[b1000[c]]]` and `1[a]1[b]1[c]1[d]1[e]1[f]1[g]` have same time complexity ? Infact, in your analysis, the time-complexity of 2nd string would be greater than the first one. However, in reality the first one would time-out while the second one(even after begin greater input length) would be solved withing no time

Comment: Don't we see the number of operations happening?

Comment: @ChrisMM I think I get what you are saying. Asymptotically its O(N) where N is the size of the input. Thanks!

Comment: @nighthowler That's right, in strict asymptotic terms, the time complexity would be consider O(N). But if we analyze based on time required, it far more than O(N) in the worst cases.